# Strange ~2px White Area Underneath Of Images. Possible CSS Error?

Tags: css, image, whitespace, html

Below I have included an image illustrating my issue. In summary, I am having an issue with an approximately 2 pixel whitespace below each of the images on my website. I'm not exactly sure what is causing this, but it is most definitely not the image itself. I believe it to be the `box-sizing: border-box` snippet in my CSS, due to the fact that 2px would be the sum of the top and bottom borders, however, removing that part of the code does not solve the issue. Any help or tips would be greatly appreciated. I have tried viewing the webpage on my mobile phone, using Firefox and using Chrome, and the issue is persistent between all of them.

[image: Illustration of whitespace below images]

The webpage in question can be found at http://www.bellasaluminum.com/gallery.php?jobType=GlassWindow&page=1, however, I have included a portion of the gallery's stylesheet below:

```
#gallery > div {
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 5px;
    width: auto;
}

#gallery > div > * {
    display: inline-block;
}

#gallery > div > img {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

#gallery > div > div.description {
    position: relative;
    padding: 3px;
    width: auto;
    vertical-align: top;
}

#galleryNav {
    padding: 0px;
    background-color: #dedede;
    text-align: center;
    border-left: 2px solid black;
    border-right: 2px solid black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    width: 90%;
    margin: auto;
}

#galleryNav > a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 8px 10px 8px;
    margin: 0px;
}

#galleryNav > a:hover {
    background-color: #efefef;
}

#galleryNav > a.active {
    background-color: #afafaf;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can either make the `img` elements `block` level:

```
#gallery > div > img {
    display:block;
}
```

or, change the `vertical-align` property value to something like `top`. (the default is `baseline`)

```
#gallery > div > img {
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

The second option (`vertical-align:top`) should be used in this instance, because you want the text to be `inline` with the `img` element.

Comment: making the image have `vertical-align: top;` fixed the issue. That is so weird... But Thanks!